# ng-view directive won't load on ie11 from sfdc server

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

everything works well on chrome but no matter what I try I can't get the ng-view directive to display my templates on ie11 (only the header and footer get displayed)

I've tried compatibility mode on ie11 and also tried div ng-view='' /div but not working... any suggsetions would be greatly appreciated.

```
<apex:page showheader="false" sidebar="false"         standardstylesheets="false" 
            cache="false" expires="600" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" 
            docType="html-5.0" 
            controller="CE_RemoteController">
<html ng-app="MyApp">
   <head>
      <!-- Meta Tags -->
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, minimum-        scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
      <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

```
<body ng-controller="mainController as main" ng-cloak="true">
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

Comment: do you have an update on this, how it was solved? I am using Angular 1.5.3, ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js and on IE11 the page is not showing the styles as in chrome. Another thing is that in Chrome, when I am using routes, Chrome is not showing the pages right, only when I refresh. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

You are likely to be using a more recent version of Angular but in case this is of any help to you...

I have an Angular 1.2.7 app that following these [compatibility instructions](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/docs/guide/ie) works on IE9, IE10 and IE11. It includes these elements:

```
<apex:page controller="IndexController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false"
        standardStylesheets="false" applyHtmlTag="false" docType="html-5.0">

<html lang="en" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app"
        ng-app="eepApp" ng-controller="AppController">
...
<div id="partials" ng-view="partials"></div>
...
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but unfortunately I am using angular 1.4.2... I've tried switching angular versions and followed the compatibility instructions that you gave but with no success.. thanks for your time..

Comment: @tercou1 Presume it is working fine in e.g. Chrome?

Comment: yes it is working perfectly in chrome etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the server hosting your JS file to IE trusted sites. I have run into this with applications within Salesforce in IE.